# Add another button removes the default values from my fields on node form

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I have a node form on which two fields are displaying.
One is a list of radio buttons which is required field.

I am getting a value from url using `arg(3)` and setting the default value of that field

```
$form['field_test'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#default_value'] = arg(3);
```

I have a link field which is a multi valued field. It means this field as `add another button`.

When I click on this `add another button` and then submit the form, I see an error of Test field is required, and that default value of `test field` gone.

Without clicking the `add another button` everything works fine.

How can I set a default value of the test field in this case?

Code:

```
if (!$form['nid']['#value']) {
  if (arg(3)) {
    // Select the default value.
    $tg = arg(3);
    $form['field_test'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#default_value'] = $tg;
  }
}

  // Make the field readonly.
  $form['field_test'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';
```

Comment: Looks like you are ignoring delta? Also please post the form code.

Comment: Added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found the solution. Let me share my code here.

I stored the argument in the `$form_state['storage]` so that it can be preserved during the ajax call.

```
if (arg(0) == 'node' && arg(3)) {
    $form_state['storage']['field_test_value'] = arg(3);
}

// Only on node creation.
if (!$form['nid']['#value'] && isset($form_state['storage'])) {
    $form['field_test'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#default_value'] = $form_state['storage']['field_test_value'];
}

$form['field_test'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';
```

Hope this will help someone.